# How to update posts' custom taxonomy selection?

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy

It's rather easy to update post meta_data using this:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'status', 'active');
```

Since I was recommended to use custom taxonomy instead, I have registered and created a custom taxonomy 'status', by pasting the below code in my functions.php:

```
//* Add custom taxonomy 'status' *//

function wporg_register_taxonomy_status() {
     $labels = array(
         'name'              => _x( 'Status', 'taxonomy general name' ),
         'singular_name'     => _x( 'Status', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
         'search_items'      => __( 'Search Status' ),
         'all_items'         => __( 'All Status' ),
         'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Status' ),
         'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Status:' ),
         'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Status' ),
         'update_item'       => __( 'Update Status' ),
         'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Status' ),
         'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Status Name' ),
         'menu_name'         => __( 'Status' ),
     );
     $args   = array(
         'hierarchical'      => true, // make it hierarchical (like categories)
         'labels'            => $labels,
         'show_ui'           => true,
         'show_admin_column' => true,
         'query_var'         => true,
         'rewrite'           => [ 'slug' => 'status' ],
     );
     register_taxonomy( 'status', [ 'post' ], $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wporg_register_taxonomy_status' );
```

Ok, so now I have my custom taxonomy 'status'.

I have gone to Posts > Status inside the wp dashboard and created two entries named:

Active

Inactive

both have the same slugs.

Active has term_id: 661
Inactive has term_id: 662

Inside my create custom post form I have added this line so that when the post is created, it would automatically set the taxonomy to 'active':

```
<input type="hidden" name="usp-taxonomy-status[]" value="661" />
```

So now I have all new posts with selected status taxonomy to 'active'.

My question is how to use `update_term_meta()` to update my selection?

Or should I use  `wp_set_post_terms ();` ?

In a nutshell I want something like this:

```
update_term_meta ($post_id, 'status', 'inactive');
//and at the same time 
uncheck the 'status', 'active';
```

So that only one 'inactive' would be left selected.

Need help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted using this:

To set to active:

```
    <?php  $post_id = 58;
      $tag = array( 661 );
         wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tag, 'status' ); ?>
```

To set to inactive:

```
    <?php  $post_id = 58;
      $tag = array( 662 );
         wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tag, 'status' ); ?>
```